# Inserting command with optional argument as optional argument Problem

Tags: macros, errors, optional-arguments

If I define the following two commands:

```
\newcommand{\TestA}[1][]{a^{#1} aaa}
\newcommand{\TestB}[1][]{#1}
```

and then call it  by

```
$\TestA[\TestB[111]]$
```

I get the error:

```
"Argument of \\TestB has an extra  }."
```

But $\TestB[111]$ and $\TestA[111]$ works...

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). When asking questions it is better to provide a full [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) both in order to demonstrate what you are trying to do and to help others help you. The MWE should look like `\documentclass...\begin{document}...\end{document}`, it should compile and contain close to the minimal amount of code needed to explain/demonstrate what you are asking. This saves everyone time:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are confusing latex with the square backets for the optional arguments. When latex sees

```
 \TestA[\TestB[111]]
```

it thinks that the optional argument for `\TestA` is `\TestB[111`. Now it tries to evaluate this expression and gets confused because `\TestB` is not conforming to syntax.

To fix this you need to put brackets around the optional argument to `\TestA`:

```
\TestA[{\TestB[111]}]
```

Comment: Thanks. This workaround solves the problem. Nevertheless in my opinion I would expect Latex to behave differently...